# How to fix the Error using fprintf Unable to convert 'sym' value to 'double'.?

Tags: matlab, double

```
Error using fprintf
Unable to convert 'sym' value to 'double'.
```

This is my input

```
Step size = .2

dy/dt = f(t,y) = exp(-x*y)

y0 = 0

t0 = .1

final t = .5

n       tn          yn          yn+1

0    0.100000    0.000000    Error using fprintf

Unable to convert 'sym' value to 'double'.

Error in FinalEuler (line 17)

fprintf('%d\t %f\t %f\t %f\n',n,x,yn,y1,y2);
```

This is the code i've been using.

```
clc
syms y t x
h=input('Step size = '); 
f_e=input('dy/dt = f(t,y) = ')
f_de=f_e
yn=input('y0 = ')
tn=input('t0 = ')
t_end=input('final t = ')
n=0

%iteration
fprintf('n\t\ttn\t\t\tyn\t\t\tyn+1\n');
for x=tn:h:t_end
y1=yn+subs(f_e,t,x)*h
y2=subs(y1,y,yn)
fprintf('%d\t %f\t %f\t %f\n',n,x,yn,y1,y2);

yn=y2;
 n=n+1
end
```

How can i fix my program code?
What specific code do i need to adust or fix?

Answer (score 0):

`y1` and `y2` are symbolic variables (check why type `whos y1 y2`, or `class(y1)`) and not doubles. You are trying to display them as floats using `fprintf`, but prior to displaying you should convert the symbolic expression to a double:

```
y1 = double(yn+subs(f_e,t,x)*h);
y2 = double(subs(y1,y,yn))
```

Or alternatively, only convert `y1` and `y2` to doubles only for displaying, and keep them symbolic for the next iteration.

```
fprintf('%d\t %f\t %f\t %f\n',n,x,yn,double(y1),double(y2));
```